# The typing goes slow inside contenteditable with Firefox on Mac OS

Tags: performance, macos, firefox, contenteditable, aloha-editor

The typing goes slow inside contenteditable only with Firefox on Mac OS.
In this case doesn't happen with another browsers.
I try reproduce this case with Firefox on Windows OS. It works!!

I found this problem on : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=458051

And you can test on this linl : https://bug458051.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=341294

But it haven't had any solution to solve it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-beta build of Firefox could solve this problem.
http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/